# In which circumstances does the community review whether to reopen this question as of n hours ago?

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

Recently I have observed a gold language tag badge holder hammering a couple of questions as duplicates. Among the several questions the user has marked as duplicate today, a couple of them contain the banner text:

[image: The community is reviewing whether to reopen this question as of 7 hours ago.]

What can be the significance of this community review banner?

Comment: That it entered the reopen review queue?

Comment: But, I don't see any _Reopen_ votes casted as of now

Comment: Edits can also have this effect under some circumstances.

Comment: But the last edit was 23 hours ago while the hammering was done 6 hours back.

Comment: @RobertLongson Regular users with <3k rep can't flag for reopening.

Comment: I must admit, I find it odd the gold badger reopened the post to close it again as the same dupe target. That doesnt achieve anything other than to invalid the prior users' close votes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[cruisepandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9444073/cruisepandey) appears to have been celebrating the earning of his shiny new [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) gold badge, which [he earned earlier today (2021-11-14 07:49:42Z)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5115/selenium?userid=9444073), only 7 minutes before he voted to reopen [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955750/how-to-address-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-using-selenium-a) (at 2021-11-14 07:57:46Z).

Immediately after reopening, he voted to close the question again (at 2021-11-14 07:58:05Z), as a duplicate of the same question that it was originally closed as a duplicate of.

I will not pretend to understand exactly why cruisepandey may have done this. Maybe it was a mistake, or maybe he was literally trying out the new gold hammer privileges that he had earned. Either explanation is reasonable; he didn't do any lasting damage or leave content unmoderated. No harm, no foul.

But there's still something interesting here: cruisepandey hit the *exact* same bug that's been… *bugging* me lately. You see, his vote to reopen the question put the question into the [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30336511). Normally, that makes sense: a single reopen vote isn't sufficient to reach the threshold to reopen the question, so it creates a reopen review task for the question. Except in this case, where cruisepandey's gold tag badge gave him the privileges to immediately reach the threshold, thus reopening the question, without any need for the involvement of other users or a review queue.

I've been experiencing the same problem when I use my moderator privileges to reopen a question and, shortly thereafter, close it again. My vote to reopen puts the question into the reopen review queue *even though it has already been fully reopened*.

This is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): **binding reopen votes** (whether from a diamond moderator or a gold tag-badge holder) **should not enqueue the question in the reopen review queue**. I wish for this bug to be fixed. Don't you wish that, too? Maybe there is power in numbers.

(At least, as a moderator, if I remember, I can look for the associated reopen review queue task and immediately dismiss it to save others from wasting their time. A gold tag-badge holder wouldn't be able to do this even if they knew about this bug.)

Bonus [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): re-closing the question doesn't invalidate the pending reopen review task.

Comment: The bug report about this bug https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370896/213575

Comment: Well if I would get to hold a shiny new hammer and my first instinct would be to try it out on something that is right in front of me... I hope my cat isn't at that time asking for food!

Comment: You would not use your shiny new hammer to smash open a can of food for your cat, @Gimby? Seems cruel!